# How to modify my login page to retrieve values from a database

Tags: jsf, jpa, derby

I have created a very simple login form where a user enters a username and password and it checks the values stored into the backing bean and if it matches it gives you a welcome message.

This is working fine, however I am wanting to add the function of a database, to allow more users and better security.

I have created a simple web app connected to a database (derby) using the inbuilt netbeans wizzard as I found here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tql4COiN5T0

I am able to retrive data from the database, edit it view it and also destroy it, much of this functionality will be removed at the end. However, what I am wondering is, how can I instead of going to the backing bean to search for the correct values search the derby database?

This is my current facelet page:

```
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="Name"></h:outputText>
            <h:inputText value="#{loginTest.username}"></h:inputText>
            <h:outputText value="Password"></h:outputText>
            <h:inputSecret value="#{loginTest.password}"></h:inputSecret>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:commandButton value="Login" action="second"></h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
```

And here is one page where I can retrieve all the users in the database:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{logindetailsController.items}" var="item" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" rowClasses="jsfcrud_odd_row,jsfcrud_even_row" rules="all" style="border:solid 1px">
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListLogindetailsTitle_id}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.id}"/>
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListLogindetailsTitle_username}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.username}"/>
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListLogindetailsTitle_password}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.password}"/>
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="&nbsp;"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:commandLink action="#{logindetailsController.prepareView}" value="#{bundle.ListLogindetailsViewLink}"/>
                            <h:outputText value=" "/>
                            <h:commandLink action="#{logindetailsController.prepareEdit}" value="#{bundle.ListLogindetailsEditLink}"/>
                            <h:outputText value=" "/>
                            <h:commandLink action="#{logindetailsController.destroy}" value="#{bundle.ListLogindetailsDestroyLink}"/>
                        </h:column>
                    </h:dataTable>
```

I have a backing bean where I am able to retrieve all the usernames and passwords. How would I search for the correct username and password in this bean?

Here is the entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOGINDETAILS")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Logindetails.findAll", query = "SELECT l FROM Logindetails l"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Logindetails.findById", query = "SELECT l FROM Logindetails l WHERE l.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Logindetails.findByUsername", query = "SELECT l FROM Logindetails l WHERE l.username = :username"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Logindetails.findByPassword", query = "SELECT l FROM Logindetails l WHERE l.password = :password")})
public class Logindetails implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Short id;
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    private String username;
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;

// getters and setters
```

Comment: can you be more specific? i'm having issues to get the point of the question.

Comment: How can i search the database from the login page and return success or fail if the user name and password are in the database

Comment: So .. Basically your question is, you have no clue how to perform in JPA/JPQL a `SELECT` with a `WHERE` on both the `username` and the `password` fields in order to get exactly the desired `Logindetails` entity matching the supplied username and password, or `null` if there's no match? I'm not sure how that's remotely related to JSF.

Comment: i strongly recommend start reading http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html to get the basics of performing queries from your managedBeans, or try starting from scratch with  Java EE 6 Development with NetBeans 7 book.

Comment: @berkay: that tutorial is targeted on JDBC and OP is using JPA.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you well, you should instanciate the entity in the appropriate managed-bean, to use it in the view like this:

```
<h:form>
    ...
        <h:inputText value="#{loginTest.logindet.username}"></h:inputText>
    ...
        <h:inputSecret value="#{loginTest.logindet.password}"></h:inputSecret>

    <h:commandButton value="Login" action="second"></h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

With :

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginTest implements Serializable {

    public Logindetails logindet;


    public LoginTest(){}

    public String login(){
        // login process
    }
 }
```